# Using Einstein Engagement Scoring with IP Whitelisting

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein

I'm looking to enable Einstein Engagement Scoring on an account.

According to the list of [Prerequisites for Einstein Engagement Scoring](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_anb_prerequisites_einstein_engagement_scoring.htm&type=5), the documentation states:

> Einstein Engagement Scoring is not compatible with IP whitelisting.

I assume that this refers to IP whitelisting setting below from Administration > Security > Security Settings > Restrict Logins by IP Address, as per the below screenshot.

[image: IP whitelisting]

I don't understand the correlation between this application and IP whitelisting. Perhaps Marketing Cloud uses a different platform to perform the [Engagement Scoring model confidence scoring](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_anb_model_confidence.htm&type=5) and it needs to impersonate a user account to get access?!

IP whitelisting is enabled on this account, but has the setting set to 'Log whitelist violations' (not 'Log Violations & Deny Access'). So you can still access the account from outside the whitelist, but will just require Identity Verification (by email).

Has anyone enabled Einstein Engagement Scoring with IP whitelisting configured? I just want to ensure that I cover all prerequisites before requesting [this feature to be activated](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_anb_activate_einstein_engagement_scoring.htm&type=5).

Answer (score 1):

This does refer to IP login whitelisting, since this data is loaded into MC from the Einstein platform outside the SFMC, but this issue has been resolved and this is no longer an issue since the IP have been whitelisted by SFMC